# How can i add test data in Extent Report?

Tags: selenium, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I want to add test data used in test case execution in Extent Report selenium.
e.g. I have used username soni691 & password: 691990 in a login method. Then if this test case is passed I want to display in the extent report that this username & pwd is used to login into the page.

I want to know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

On the ExtentTest instance you can call the info method which accepts any String. Apart from info you can call pass, fail, error and a few more. Use these to log the steps and assertions you take.

You could try something like the below.

```
ExtentReports extentReports = new ExtentReports();
ExtentTest test = extentReports.createTest("SomeName");
ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("Test.html");//Constructor takes a path
extentReports.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
String user = "MyUser";
String pass = "MyPass";
test.info(String.format("username: %s; password: %s", user, pass));
reports.flush();
```

pom.xml dependency:

```
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
```

EDIT: Since I cant comment yet Ill just edit the answer.

The source of data wont matter as long as you can make a String out of it. Since you can send the username and password I suppose you already have them in some variable.

EDIT2: I wrote the wrong variable name here. Didnt mean extent but rather extentReports which I initilized the row before.

EDIT3: Added flush to finish up the flow of creating a whole report.

EDIT4: Added Maven dependancy to be clear about the version and version number of the extent report used

EDIT5: Added Reporter

Comment: One more thing i want to add here that I am fetching test data from an excel sheet.In that case this will still work?

Comment: ExtentTest test = extent.createTest("SomeName"); in this createTest indicates the actual method you mean?  I am little confused so. As i tried (extentTest.info(String.format("username: %s; password: %s", UserName, Password));) but it says "The method info(String) is undefined for the type ExtentTest"

Comment: You are using Java?

Comment: Yes i am using java with POM and data driven framework

Comment: Strange, I just did the flow above and it works fine. I am using the extentreports artifactId version 3.0.1. As for the createTest method it should be a built in method for the ExtentReports class

Comment: I want to know extentReports.createTest("SomeName"); what is the createTest means? I can use my login method instead of createTest ? e.g. `ExtentTest Test = extent.LoginToCRM("SomeName");
extentTest.info(String.format("username: %s; password: %s", UserName, Password));`

Comment: I am not able to get createTest method in my Extend report class by default

Comment: createTest method means you are running a new test. In the example you provide it would be a test named "LoginToCRM" after that you would run your test and log some result - for instance how you logged in. After that you might have a test "Create new CRM user" you would again call the createTest method on ExtentReports.


Could you put your extent dependency from the pom here?

Comment: Are you using com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports & 
`<dependency>
   <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
   <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
   <version>2.41.2</version>
  </dependency>` version?

Comment: Ah so, it seems we have different extentreports. That would explain a lot. I also use 3.0.1 version - just tried the new v5 but that one is also missing the method. `<groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>`

Comment: In which section of ExtentReport the test data will display?

Comment: I tried with 4.0.0 dependency & able to generate the report but test data is not displayed in the report.

Comment: It should show up in the test step as the category you used (Such as info, pass, fail etc.)
Making a html report?

Comment: used below code `setUsername(UserName);
         setPassword(Password);
   ExtentReports extentReports = new ExtentReports();
   ExtentTest test = extentReports.createTest("Login Method");
   test.info(String.format("username: %s; password: %s", UserName, Password));` is this ok?   Yes making html report

Comment: Try adding a reporter. Its in the edited answer now

Comment: At the end of exectuion add: reports.flush(); if you havent already

Comment: So do i need to provide the path in constructor?I have already created an ExtentReprotListener class.in that i provide `extent = new ExtentReports(outputDirectory + File.separator
    + "Extent.html", true);`

Comment: How to fetch test data from an excel sheet?